# Avoid building all VB.NET projects in a VisualStudio solution

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

We create a class library and ship C# and VB.NET examples.

I have a solution of 60 C# projects. If I make an edit to one of them, Visual Studio only builds the changed one.

I have an equivalent solution of 60 VB.NET projects. Visual Studio always builds all 60 projects. Why? Is there a way to force Visual Studio to behave like it does with C# projects?

I should mention that there are no dependencies between the projects.

More information: It's not recompiling, really, it's just checking if they need compilation and that takes a significant amount of time.

Here's the build output:

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 3 failed, 58 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Those 58 checks take about 30 seconds in my solution of VB.NET projects. This same up-to-date check is almost instant in the solution of C# projects.

No edit is necessary. Just switching startup projects is enough.

Comment: Funny, I have a solution open with multiple vb projects and I can't reproduce.  I don't think we've done anything special to it.

Answer (score 1):

How this works is very dependent on how the dependencies between the projects are setup.  If all of your projects reference the project that's being edited then yes all of the projects will necessarily be rebuilt.

Can you give us some more info on the setup.  In particular what dependencies are there between the projects?

Comment: We have a class library. All projects reference that same class library. None of the projects reference each other. I have lots of C# experience and very little VB.NET experience (only enough to port C# examples) so it's possible I did something incorrectly.